# Does the SQL Standard mention trigger events on DDL (ALTER, CREATE, DROP)?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-standard, ddl-trigger

[PostgreSQL supports "Event Triggers"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html) which is defined as,

> To supplement the trigger mechanism discussed in Chapter 39, PostgreSQL also provides event triggers. Unlike regular triggers, which are attached to a single table and capture only DML events, event triggers are global to a particular database and are capable of capturing DDL events.

[SQL Server "DDL Triggers"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017),

> DDL triggers fire in response to a variety of Data Definition Language (DDL) events. These events primarily correspond to Transact-SQL statements that start with the keywords `CREATE`, `ALTER`, `DROP`, `GRANT`, `DENY`, `REVOKE` or `UPDATE STATISTICS`. Certain system stored procedures that perform DDL-like operations can also fire DDL triggers.

[Oracle simply calls them "Triggers"](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDDDG/tdddg_triggers.htm#TDDDG50000). Is there any standardized functionality that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL Spec currently only says this about Triggers,

> **4.6.5.5 Triggers**
>
> A *trigger* is an object associated with a single base table or a single viewed table. A trigger specifies a *subject table*, *trigger event*, a *trigger action time*, and one or more *triggered actions*.
>
> - A **trigger event** specifies what action on the subject table shall cause the triggered actions. A trigger event is either `INSERT`, `DELETE`, or `UPDATE`.
> - A **trigger action time** specifies whether the triggered action is to taken `BEFORE`, `INSTEAD OF`, or `AFTER` the trigger event.
> - A **triggered action** is either an `<SQL procedure statement>` or `BEGIN ATOMIC`, followed by one or more `<SQL procedure statement>`s terminated with `<semicolon>`s, followed by `END`.

Without any further mention, I believe the spec does not currently address this functionality at all.

---

Formatting slightly modified from the spec. I turned it into a list. Spec used *"Information technology — Database languages — SQL —
Part 1: Framework (SQL/Framework)"*

Comment: How about a link to the SQL Spec.

Comment: @Volte you can find the 2011n draft here https://www.wiscorp.com/SQLStandards.html SQL is a paid spec. You can just give it away or distribute it.